# clang error: unsupported: anonymous type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration after its linkage was computed

Tags: c, compiler-errors, clang

Someone knows what does this error mean?
My piece of code is shown below：

```
// test.c
inline void fun() {
    typedef struct {
        int i;
    } S;
}
```

GCC could compile without an error while clang (clang 12.0.0) claims an error:

```
root:~/test # clang -c test.c
test.c:2:19: error: unsupported: anonymous type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration after its linkage was computed; add a tag name here to establish linkage prior to definition
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                  S
test.c:4:7: note: type is given name 'S' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } S;
      ^
1 error generated.
```

According to the error text from clang, it looks like I need to add a tag name for the anonymous typedef. After adding a tag name, it won’t show an error. However, this piece of code from a team work program in my department so I need a strong reason to modify it. Someone knows what’s this error mean?

---

UPDATE: In the comments below someone mentioned, The code could compile but fail to link with GCC. Actually that because the GCC optimization is not turned on. Use -O2 to compile and link will pass.

Comment: This appears to be related to the fact that `fun` is declared `inline`. GCC does not give the same error as clang does, but it also fails to compile this a program with this function; specifically, it fails to link. Why? There is no definition for `fun`. You declared it to be `extern inline`. It *must* also have a non-inline definition somewhere in the program. Remove `inline`, or declare it as `static inline`, and this program compiles.

Comment: This doesn't compile  with a major compiler. Whoever is at fault (you, your coworkers, the compiler, the C standard, $DEITY), isn't it a strong enough reason to modify the code?

Comment: I think the question is not so much about how to fix it (in my opinion the message is clear about that: add a tag name to the struct), but rather about what causes this. I find it really confusing to see a message about the concept of linkage of types. Functions and Variables are supposed to have linkage, but types???

Comment: I believe clang messed something up there. Type linkage is apparently part of C++ (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) but to my knowledge not in C. So maybe you hit a soft spot in clang, where it does not differentiate between C and C++ in a clean way.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using -O2 compile option to compile my code which makes inline valid in GCC. When compile with -O0, GCC neither produces a symbol for the inline funciton nor extend inline, so it fails to link. However, when applied optimization, even using -O1 GCC will extend the function so the link passed. Clang behaviours the same with GCC.

Comment: If you can only compile with a specific optimisation flag, then either you have a bug or the compiler has a bug. In this case it's you, because you must define the function as non-inline somewhere. This however does not explain clang behaviour.

Comment: @JakobStark spot on. This is a clang bug.

Answer (score 4):

I mentioned this in a comment, but I think I might be able to expand it to a proper answer. The problem here is in how the `inline` keyword works in C. Quite frankly, I don't know what the C standards committee was smoking when they came up with this ridiculous concept, and it's probably best not to know. Don't ask why the rules are this way: I don't know.

There is an important difference between `extern inline` and `static inline` functions, as well as ones declared simply `inline`.

`inline` functions may be defined in a header and included in multiple compilation units. This is because they aren't considered "real" definitions. No symbol for them is emitted, thus there is no multiple-definition error. However, the compiler is not required to actually inline the function call. It may instead try to call it. Since no symbol exists, there will be an error at link time. Never use `inline` functions in C. They make no sense at all.

`extern inline` functions provide the definition for an `inline` function. If the above case happens, and the compiler tries to call the function, so long as some file includes an `extern inline` definition, there won't be an error because it emits a symbol. This making sense? No? Good.

`static inline` functions are the only one that make any sense whatsoever. Because they're `static` and therefore local, no symbol need exist. If the compiler decides to inline it, it does. If not, it calls the function. No problems. Declare your function `static inline` and it will compile.

But that wasn't your question. Why is clang complaining about the `struct`? Why doesn't gcc complain? The answer is "idunnoman". Best guess is that clang is taking the rules very seriously, in which case because there is no "real" definition for `fun`, there is also no real definition for your anonymous struct, and therefore can't be typedef'd.

But that would also be the case if it were a named struct. And why does the linker care whether the structure has a name? Once again, I can only guess it has to do with the fact that there can be numerous definitions for an `inline` function, and clang wants the structure to have a constant name between them. But different compilation units can have different structures with the same name, so that doesn't make sense either.

Ugh. I thought I had an answer for you but now I'm even more confused than when I started. I'll still post this but it probably ought to be downvoted. Oh well.

Comment: Even though this does not quite answer the question, I find it very useful and understanding the difference `static inline` vs `extern inline` vs `inline` as you described will probably help understanding the "real" cause of the error message.